# Can i Install Ubuntu on my SDCARD and improve performance?

Tags: 12.04, installation, sd-card

I am going to do a reinstall of Ubuntu on my Laptop this holiday. I have an ASUS UL30VT, with no flash drive, and i just wondered. I never use my card-reader for anything, but i have a 32GB SD-card that i do not use really. I was then wondering if installing Ubuntu on that SD-card will improve my performance much? Would it be like SSD

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install and update Ubuntu to a Pen drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106801/how-to-install-and-update-ubuntu-to-a-pen-drive)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106801/how-to-install-and-update-ubuntu-to-a-pen-drive). Any good answer to this question (like [SirCharlo's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/168882/22949)) will mention SD-specific issues.

Comment: If you buy a high end 100 MB/s read and 90 MB/s write it would be a bit faster than a normal HDD but not much...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By experience, I can tell you that running Ubuntu on a SD card is usually **unbearably** slow. You won't get anywhere near SSD-like performance. This is due to the read and write speed limitations of SD cards and card readers.

Installing on a USB flash drive would give you at least equal, and most likely significantly better, performance.

*Please note that I am only speaking from personal experience.*

Answer (score 3):

Worth noting that there's SD cards now that have R/W speeds of up 260MB/240MB per sec, respectively: See this [article](http://gizmodo.com/these-are-the-worlds-fastest-sd-cards-for-now-at-lea-811597534)

Comment: But, then, the read/write limitation of a typical laptop card reader may be a further limitation. Typically, SD card readers are on the USB2 bus, so we're talking a speed of less than 30 MB/sec.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this and the result wasn't pleasant(read: it was slow). The instructions I followed were:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=5cc607fc26815ce5fd89bddee599b84f&p=11915401&postcount=22

Answer (score 2):

Even using a class 10 sd card, the sequential speed would be ~10MB/s writting and ~20MB/s reading. That's not much compared to the 50+MB/s writting and 200+MB/s reading provided by entry level ssd disks.